# Merging pandas dataframe using index.searchsorted

Tags: python, merge, pandas

I would like to merge two dataframes on time, but instead of merging exactly I would like to get the max(time1) <= time2

I think that pandas index.searchsorted is the best way to do this but I can't quite figure out how to get the merge to work

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'time' :pd.Series([100., 200., 300.]),'val1' : pd.Series([10., 20., 30.])}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df1 = df1.set_index(['time'])

d2 = {'time' :pd.Series([150., 170., 305., 400.]),'val2' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.])}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
df2 = df2.set_index(['time'])
```

In this example I would like to find a dataframe that is essentially df2, but with a val1 that should be = [10, 10, 30, 30].

```
df1.index.searchsorted(df2.index)
```

The above seems to return the index I would like... but I am not sure where to go from here. Any help much appreciated!

I had hoped the following would return the correct entries, but it has an index out of bounds error

```
df1.ix(df1.index[df1.index.searchsorted(df2.index)])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `reindex`:

```
import pandas as pd

d1 = {'time' :pd.Series([100., 200., 300.]),'val1' : pd.Series([10., 20., 30.])}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df1 = df1.set_index(['time'])

d2 = {'time' :pd.Series([150., 170., 305., 400.]),'val2' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.])}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
df2 = df2.set_index(['time'])

df1.reindex(df2.index, method="ffill")
```

the output:

```
      val1
time      
150     10
170     10
305     30
400     30
```